# como inserir no banco de dados uma variável que trás uma array?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

tenho uma pagina que tem um textarea e nesse textarea o usuário vai colocar um lista de registros e nesse registros eu separo as strings com a função explode

esse é meu código html index.php

MTMs Ativos

    #login{
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding:40px 15px;
    }

```
label{
    display: block;
    margin-right: 100px;

    padding: 5px;
}

#text{
    width: 500px;
    height: 480px;
}
```

function valida(){

        if(form.text.value==""){
            alert('Preencha o campo');
            form.text.focus();
            return false;
        }
        alert("Material requerido com sucesso!");
    }

alert("test");

-->


    
        
            Material:

```
        <label for="submit"></label>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" class="input_button" id="bt_logar" value="enviar" />
    </form>
```

esse é o código inserir.php que contém a query

```
<?php 

    $conexao = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or print("erro");
    if (!$conexao) die ("<h1>Falha na conexao com o servidor!</h1>");
    $db = @mysql_select_db("test");
    if (!$db) die ("<h1>Falha na conexao com o Banco de Dados!</h1>");



    $text = $_POST["text"];
    //echo $text;

    $alterado = array("-");
    $alterar = array("");
    $replace = str_replace($alterado,$alterar,$text);   

    $novaString = chunk_split($replace,12,".");
    //echo $novaString;

    $bat = explode('.',$novaString);
    print_r($bat)."<br>";

    //insere normalmente
    $sql = @mysql_query("insert into test.tab_mtm_ativos (MTM,planta) values ('$bat','B510')  on duplicate key update mtm = values(mtm)") or die ("erro");

    @mysql_close($conexao, $sql);
    header('location: mtm.php');

?>
```

Comment: Eu te aconselhei a codificar como json na resposta abaixo, mas lembrando que por padrão não é correto fazer isso em um banco de dados relacional. Se você procura por campos multidimensionais e dinâmicos, procure uma solução no-sql

Answer (score 1):

Bem, em um banco de dados relacional não é possível que se insira o tipo array em uma tabela. Você terá que inserir como uma string, o que pode ser feito é escolher um formato de string que abranja vetores, como JSON ou XML.

Como é um array simples, eu aconselho que você converta para JSON antes de inserir no banco de dados com a função json_encode, e toda vez que for buscar esses dados decodifique-os com a função json_decode.

Após explodir a array, codifique-a assim:

```
 $bat = explode('.',$novaString);
 $bat = json_encode($bat);
```

Isso fará que a sua array $bat, vire uma string, quando você precisar buscá-la para utilizá-la como uma array novamente, utilize:

```
$bat_array = json_decode($bat);
```

Para mais informações, visite:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

e

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

Comment: usei essa função json_encode continua inserindo em array no banco

Comment: eu entendi errado, pensei que você quisesse inserir o array. Pode colar aqui como está sendo inserido no banco?